# JodaTime IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format

Tags: java, exception, format, jodatime

this Code is throwing the "invalid format" or "malformed" Exception:

Code:

```
strDate = "21/10/2015 12:00:00 AM";
format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";

DateTime.parse(strDate, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format)).toDate();
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "21/10/2015 12:00:00 AM"
is malformed at "AM"
```

What's wrong?

I'm ussing joda-time:2.8.1

(I already searched and i think this is the correct pattern for that strDate)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text of the `AM/PM` marker may be different to that of your default locale. You could do

```
Date date = 
  DateTime.parse(strDate, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format).withLocale(Locale.US)).toDate();
```

Comment: ok this code worked, thank you, additionaly i updated the JodaTime version to 2.9

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the locale, you may specify the *locale* and *timezone* :

these should work for you:

```
DateTime.parse(strDate, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format).withLocale(Locale.US)).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate();
```

or

```
DateTime.parse(strDate, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format).withLocale(Locale.US)).toDate();
```